# Upload to a remote server using wp_remote_post

Tags: plugin-development, curl

I'am developing a plugin that will push files to a remote server via http upload. Currently I got it to work with CURL doing something like this:

```
$post = array("post_file"=>"@/path/FILE.EXT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Now my question is how I can achieve the same using wp_remote_host. How is the file included in the 'body' argument.

For more info see this.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_post

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps.

```
$args['body'] = array('post_file'=>'@/path/FILE.EXT');
wp_remote_post($url, $args);
```

The $args array contains the parameters for the post. The body parameter controls what is posted. There's many other possible parameters as well. See http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments

Note that the @file method may be specific to curl, and might not work with the other possible HTTP transports that WP supports.

Answer (score 0):

I read through the source code in wp-includes/class-http.php and `wp_remote_post()` doesn't support sending files. I think you'd need to re-write the WP_Http class to make this work or otherwise write a plugin or extension to handle this.